# TypeError: Dbschema(Mongoose Schema) is not a function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a simple registration form using MEAN_Stack using mongoose. Here is my **models/dbSchema.js**

```html
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new mongoose.Schema({
   FirstName: String,
   LastName:  String,
   City    :  String,
   Email   :  String,
   Userid  :  String,
   Password:  String
});
module.export = mongoose.model('user', User);
```

and this is my **server.js**

```html
var express = require('express');
var app =  express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Regis_module');
var Userschema = require('./models/dbSchema'); 

app.post('/regi',function(req,res){
    var schema        =  new Userschema();
    schema.Firstname      =  req.body.Fname;
    schema.Lastname      =  req.body.Lname;
    schema.City       =  req.body.city;
    schema.Email      =  req.body.email;
    schema.Userid     =  req.body.userid;
    schema.Password   =  req.body.password;
     
    schema.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Record Inserted', Firstname: req.body.firstname, Lastname: req.body.lastname, city:req.body.city, email:req.body.email, 
                   userid:req.body.userid, password :req.body.password /*, fbId : req.body.fbId*/ });
    });        
});
    
app.listen(3000);
console.log("listening to port 3000");
```

While running on the local host, at the time of form submission, Firstname and Lastname are not stored in the database. City, Eamil, Userid and Password are storing correctly.

How can I store all things in database correctly? Please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**models/dbSchema.js**

It's `module.exports` not `module.export`. And also no need to write `var Schema = mongoose.Schema;`. There is no use of Schema variable in your code.

**server.js**

```
var schema = new Dbschema({
  FirstName  :  req.body.Fname,
  LastName   :  req.body.Lname,
  City       :  req.body.city,
  Email      :  req.body.email,
  Userid     :  req.body.userid,
  Password   :  req.body.password
});
```

or,

```
var schema = new Dbschema();

schema.FirstName  =  req.body.Fname;
schema.LastName   =  req.body.Lname;
schema.City       =  req.body.city;
schema.Email      =  req.body.email;
schema.Userid     =  req.body.userid;
schema.Password   =  req.body.password;
```

Let me know if you have any problem understanding this. I will send you full code snippet if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Sk_Arif. In this registration form i also want to upload image , could you please give me a bit idea of it. How to i will be store it in MongoDB  with all other above information ?

Comment: @AbhaySharma Adding image to database is a little complicated thing. I think you can take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370). It has some important information in comments, so read the comments also.
And please mark my answer as accepted as it fulfilled your needs.

Comment: Using above code  Firstname and LastName is not inserting in DB.

Comment: Make sure you are sending Fname and Lname to your req.body. Or change Fname and Lname to whatever you are sending from your view (i.e. firstname, lastname).